# What kind of categorical construct is the tensor product of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces. We can form the algebraic tensor product $H_1 \odot H_2$ and complete it with respect to the inner product
$$\langle \xi_1 \otimes \xi_2, \eta _1 \otimes  \eta_2 \rangle:= \langle \xi_1, \eta_1\rangle \langle \xi_2, \eta_2\rangle$$
In this way, we obtain the Hilbert space $H_1 \otimes H_2$.

Consider the category **HILB** of Hilbert spaces, say with contractive linear maps as morphisms. Can we view $H_1 \otimes H_2$ as some kind of limit in this category? Does it satisfy some useful universal property? Really, any answer can be as broad as you like. I am aware that $\otimes$ defines a bifunctor that gives us a monoidal structure on this category.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Universal_property